# exact sql query string for my 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

My Brother helped me to design a Sql string for my  access 2007 database

```
   SELECT Employee.EmpID, Employee.Name, Sum(DateDiff("s",Punches.LogIN,Punches.LogOUT)) AS THours
FROM Punches INNER JOIN Employee ON Punches.EmpID=Employee.EmpID
GROUP BY Employee.Name, Employee.EmpID;
```

this sql string will display the information from two tables (Employee, Punches) the Employee's ID, Name, THours (Total Hours of work)

Sample Result:

```
EmpID   Name    THours
0001    Emp1    14560
0003    Emp3       13
0004    Emp4    43585
```

My problem is I want also to display those employees that doesnt have yet total working hours  in punches table but already in employees table.

Like this

```
EmpID   Name    THours
    0001    Emp1    14560
    0002    Emp2       0
    0003    Emp3       13
    0004    Emp4    43585
```

Any idea how to make it happen? Thank you in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Employee.EmpID, Employee.Name, Sum(NZ(DateDiff("s",Punches.LogIN,Punches.LogOUT),0)) AS THours
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Punches  
    ON Punches.EmpID=Employee.EmpID
GROUP BY Employee.Name, Employee.EmpID
ORDER BY Employee.EmpID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employee.EmpID, Employee.Name, Sum(DateDiff("s",COALESCE(Punches.LogIN, 0),COALESCE(Punches.LogOUT, 0)) AS THours
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Punches
ON Punches.EmpID=Employee.EmpID
GROUP BY Employee.Name, Employee.EmpID;
```